# UICollectionView not entering the cellForItemAt method if I only have 1 element in the collection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView inside my UITableViewCell and I want to display multiple Collection Cells. It works perfectly if the numberOfItemsInSection is more than 1. But if I only want to return 1 Item it enters the numberOfItemsInSection method and returns 1. So far so good, but the cellForRowAt method is not entered when I only have 1 Item. As long as I have 2 or more Items it works perfectly.

I am currently working with the storyboard but I also tried creating the cells programmatically but it still didn't work.

Table View Cell Class

```swift
class TaskTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var taskCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var customerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!

    private var currentTask: Task!

    func initialize(task: Task) {
        currentTask = task

        taskCollectionView.delegate = self
        taskCollectionView.dataSource = self

        taskCollectionView.allowsSelection = false
        taskCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentTask.tasks.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Not entering if numberOfItems is 1
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SingleTaskCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleTaskCollectionViewCell

        cell.setUpViews()

        return cell
    }
}
```

CollectionViewCell Class

```swift
class SingleTaskCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func setUpViews() {
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = SIZE.CORNER_RADIUS_1
    }
}
```

Task Class

```swift
class Task {
    var id: Int!
    var tasks: [String]
    var date: Date?
    var customer: Customer
    var isFinished: Bool
    var isAppointment: Bool

    init(id: Int? = nil, tasks: [String], date: String? = nil, formattedDate: Date? = nil, customer: Customer, isFinished: Bool = false, isAppointment: Bool = false) {
        if id != nil {
            self.id = id
        }
        self.tasks = tasks
        if formattedDate != nil {
            self.date = formattedDate!
        } else {
            if date != nil {
                let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                self.date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: date!)!
            } else {
                self.date = nil
            }
        }

        self.customer = customer
        self.isFinished = isFinished
        self.isAppointment = isAppointment
    }
}
```

Comment: The details of the Task type seem relevant here. Can you add that code?

Comment: Really, the only way the collectionView doesn't call cellForItemAt is if currentTask.tasks.count == 0 (or if the delegate hasn't been set).

Comment: I added the Task Class

Comment: I debugged the code and when the count is 1 it clearly return 1 in the function but doesn't enter the cellForItemAt

Comment: That's pretty weird. Try hardcoding the return value as 1 in numberOfItemsInSection.

Comment: I actually done that and then there is no Collection Cell displaying

Comment: Does cellForItem get called when numberOfItemsInSection is hardcoded to return 1? And are you sure that numberOfItemsInSection is called when this is the case?

Comment: As an aside, this might be easier to work with if the delegate and data source logic for the collection view wasn't embedded in the table view cell. It's not necessarily wrong as is, but it smells funny, and the table view cells are created, reused and destroyed by the system in ways and at times that aren't necessarily obvious.

Comment: If I hardcode to return 1 numberOfItemsInSection is called and cellForItem is not

Comment: Alright... that's bizarre. Something else must be going on here. I'd advise you to try setting the collection view up how you want it in a separate project that only contains what's needed to show and populate the collection view. Convince yourself that it works, get comfortable with how it works, then move that functionality into your main project inside the table.

Comment: show your main view controller that houses the UITableView, this isn't enough code and in that main view controller, you should be overriding - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ... to set values for the UICollectionView that is nested inside the UITableViewCell, when you call those method sin willDisplayCell, the methods inside the UITableViewCell for the UICollectionView should then call "reload" data.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I fixed it. The mistake was with the autoresizing of the cells. Because of that if I had only 1 cell it wouldn't display in the visible region and that's why cellForItemAt wasn't called.

I fixed it by changing up some settings in the storyboard and calculate the size of the cells in the sizeForItemAt method.

Comment: Nice. Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

CellforRow at:indexPath method won't be called if the size or position of the collectionView is changed before reload, make sure you're not doing that.